# Linux script to create a wiki file for mediawiki

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, mediawiki

Hi I like to create a script that will append to an existing file:  here is how the file looks:

```
{| border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="2" style="text-align: center;"
|-
! DataStore-1:
! 11/14/12
! 11/16/12
! 11/30/12
|-
| Total ios
| [[File:datastore-1-Tios-11-14-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-Tios-11-16-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-Tios-11-30-2012.png| 100px]]
|-
| Read % 
| [[File:datastore-1-readp-11-14-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-readp-11-16-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-readp-11-30-2012.png| 100px]]
|-
| Cache Hit %
| [[File:datastore-1-cachep-11-14-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-cachep-11-16-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-cachep-11-30-2012.png| 100px]]
|-
| Current kB/sec
| [[File:datastore-1-ckbsec-11-14-2012.png| 100px]]
|  [[File:datastore-1-ckbsec-11-16-2012.png| 100px]]
|  [[File:datastore-1-ckbsec-11-30-2012.png| 100px]]
|-
| Maximum kB/sec 
| [[File:datastore-1-mkbsec-11-14-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-mkbsec-11-16-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-mkbsec-11-30-2012.png| 100px]]
|-
| Current IO/sec
| [[File:datastore-1-ciosec-11-14-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-ciosec-11-16-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-ciosec-11-30-2012.png| 100px]]
|-
| Max IO/sec
| [[File:datastore-1-miosec-11-14-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-miosec-11-16-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-miosec-11-30-2012.png| 100px]]
|-
|}
```

basically i want to be able to add an entry for "date" under the DataStore-1 field for instance:

```
|-
! DataStore-1:
! 11/14/12
! 11/16/12
! 11/30/12
! 12/03/12
|-
```

Once i do that I will like to also add the an additional entry for each of the other fields that is using the same variable date for example:

```
| -
| Total ios
| [[File:datastore-1-Tios-11-14-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-Tios-11-16-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-Tios-11-30-2012.png| 100px]]
| [[File:datastore-1-Tios-12-03-2012.png| 100px]]  
|-
[...]
```

I was looking into creating a function for each section of my file, but my logic is to enough...

```
writedates ()
{
        SOURCEFILE=/mnt/bacchuscore-logger/netmon/wikipages/sourcefile.wk
        DATASTORENUM=`head -1 $SOURCEFILE|cut -d '=' -f2`
        DATESECTION=dates.sec
        DATEOUTPUT=newdates.sec
        i=0
        while read; do
                VAR[$i]=$REPLY
                DSN=$(echo ${VAR[0]}|cut -d '=' -f2)
                DSF=$(echo ${VAR[1]}|cut -d '=' -f2)
                DE=$(echo ${VAR[2]}|cut -d '=' -f2)
                echo "! $DSF-$DSN"
                echo "! $DE"
                echo "|-"
                ((i++))
        done < $SOURCEFILE
}
```

thanks

Comment: 1) Ask yourself if you can transpose this table.  Adding rows is simpler.  2) Resort to templates.  Still better to have lines `{{Total-ios|11-14-2012|11-16-2012|11-30-2012}}` which represent whole table rows.

Answer (score 0):

These script lines insert the additional entries in your file, assuming the variable `date` contains the new date (e. g. `date=12/03/12`) and the file is named `datastore`:

```
set ${date//// }; datex=$1-$2-20$3.png
sed -f-<<EOF -i datastore
/^! DataStore-1:/,/^|-/s,^|-,! $date\n&,
/^| Total ios/,/^|-/s,^|-,| [[File:datastore-1-Tios-$datex| 100px]]\n&,
/^| Read %/,/^|-/s,^|-,| [[File:datastore-1-readp-$datex| 100px]]\n&,
/^| Cache Hit %/,/^|-/s,^|-,| [[File:datastore-1-cachep-$datex| 100px]]\n&,
/^| Current kB\/sec/,/^|-/s,^|-,| [[File:datastore-1-ckbsec-$datex| 100px]]\n&,
/^| Maximum kB\/sec/,/^|-/s,^|-,| [[File:datastore-1-mkbsec-$datex| 100px]]\n&,
/^| Current IO\/sec/,/^|-/s,^|-,| [[File:datastore-1-ciosec-$datex| 100px]]\n&,
/^| Max IO\/sec/,/^|-/s,^|-,| [[File:datastore-1-miosec-$datex| 100px]]\n&,
EOF
```